# Django with multiple websites, shared apps, one domain, Apache server

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, django-wsgi

The goal is to have several websites running on one domain, with Apache and wsgi

What I currently have is one virtualhost configuration:
`WSGIScriptAlias /site1 /opt/django/wsgi.py process-group=site1`

Since there is only one project, there is only one wsgi.py, so all apps are running under domain.com/site1, i.e. site2 is available at domain.com/site1/site2 which is not what I want.

The desired config is :
site1 reachable at domain.com/site1
site2 reachable at domain.com/site2.

Also, there are some shared apps between site1 and site2.

project/urls.py configuration:
`path('', include(('site1.urls', 'site1'), namespace='site1')), path('/site2', include(('site2.urls', 'site2'), namespace='site2')),`